# Does Size of 6-Pin Tactile Switch Affect Spacing of Pins?

Tags: switches, pins

I don't have these locally so I have to order from abroad:
[image]

My question is would 7mm x 7mm dimensions of plastic core affect spacing between pins? I can't find 7.5mm x 7.5mm size to replace failed switch but I can find 7mm x 7mm and 8.5mm x 8.5mm and as long as tolerance + / - 0.5mm - 1mm will not affect spacing of pins I think I am good.

**UPDATE:** Here's one that I need to replace on IC board.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here's the datasheet I was provided:

[image]

Comment: The datasheet should tell you the pin spacing

Comment: Can you attach a link to the datasheet, please?

Comment: I can't find one. This item is sold in online store and very short description is what they have. I added photo of switch on IC.

Comment: If you need a datasheet and there is none, then no sale. If you *want* to buy it, then good luck.

Comment: Hello. I was provided datasheet. I have updated original post.

Comment: A picture of a table is *not* a datasheet, it is a picture of a table. A actual datasheet would have at minimum a proper mechanical drawing, and information beyond what one can get from the switch and a ruler.

Comment: Well, the Chinese seller does not understand that and keeps sending me table. Not all sellers are good at understanding what they are selling.

Answer (score 5):

You CANNOT assume pin spacing from case size. You MUST refer to the manufacturer's data sheet which will show EXACTLY what is the pin spacing, pin/hole size, and connection pinout.  DO NOT ASSUME anything, especially if you need compatibility or design of a PC board.

Comment: I can't find one. This item is sold in online store and very short description is what they have. I added photo of switch on IC.

Comment: Hi Richard. I was provided datasheet. I have updated original question.

Comment: That is just an extracted summary of SOME of the specification parameters. A proper data sheet is typically several pages and includes detailed drawings of the pin spacing, etc.  If this is you only option, then you have little choice but buy one (or more) and measure or try it for yourself. If you can't find the REAL manufacturers data sheet, then you have NO WAY of answering your question definitively.

Comment: How hard it would be for someone who soldered only once in their life to have this switch (top photo) soldered to small PCB (photo below it)?

Comment: Do you have a clean, empty board?  Or do you have to remove the faulty switch first?  Even soldering to a new, clean board is not a simple job for a beginner. And removing a bad switch will likely be very challenging for a beginner.  Do you know anyone in your neighborhood who knows how to solder?

Comment: Switch must be removed. No I don't have anyone who knows soldering. I was told before that task may be not easy for the first timer before so I will hold off for now. Maybe will drop it and trash the coffee whisker. Yes, it was a small battery-powered whisker that needed switch replaced. I am just one who likes to tinker with tech stuff but lack experience. At least not with tinkering with PCs.

Comment: It can't hurt to watch some YouTube tutorials about desoldering. And get some good flux and "solder braid" which soaks up the solder.  They are not expensive on Ebay, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is the pitch (spacing) of the pins of the switch you are trying to replace? Which should also be the pitch of the holes in the PC board, etc.  A proper data sheet shows detailed mechanical drawings including pin spacing patterns, etc. etc. For example, here is a 7mm x 7mm, 6-pin switch with mechanical drawings. It may or may not match YOUR switch:

[image]

It shows that the adjacent pins are 2mm apart, and the two opposite rows are 5mm apart.

Ref: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Latching-7x7mm-Mini-Tactile-Push-Button_60227167979.html

Answer (score 0):

These "look like" standard DIP 6 pins 0.1 " spacing 0.3" 7.62mm pitch
[image]

Although some other species of DIP may be 2mm vs 2.54mm pitch especially if they have round pins. But these are std flat lead-frames.